# Risks of Mass Assignment in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, security, laravel

I started using Laravel with 4.0 where mass assignment was available by default... i.e.

```
$foo = Foo::create('foo' => 'bar', 'bar' => 'foo');
```

But I think in L4.1 fields available for mass assignment started having to be defined in the model.  Now I'm going through a tutorial for L5 since I had learned L4 mostly through trial and error and I'm seeing mass assignment used on a lot of models that I would thing to be rather high risk, such as Users.

I kind of expect to get flagged for asking for an opinion, but I'm unclear on what risks I'm worried about with mass assignment (SQL injection I'm assuming). Or does the fact that I'm defining what is mass assignable in the model take away the risk that was in the L4.0 system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "risk" is that developers often pass `Input::all()` into the model. Without the protection that the new system with `$fillable` and `$guarded` provides, unexpected user input can produce an error (to be exact an SQL error like: `column foo not in field list`) and it possibly allows the user to insert attributes you didn't want him to set by manipulating the request.

Comment: So as long as I define $fillable and $guarded am I safe passing an array directly from the form?  I've seen the method of each input having a name like form['user_name'] or form['password'] which seems elegant, but I was assuming that passing that array to the model would be risky.